# Logging formatter in Python causes stack_info to be printed twice

Tags: python, json, logging, filebeat

I'm trying to structure the logging output into JSON format for a Python (3.8.3) application to be picked up by Filebeat and sent to Elasticsearch. This works great for regular logging statements, but when I want to include the stack trace on errors (by setting stack_info to True) the Stack Trace is printed an additional time as the following code examplifies:

```
import logging

def get_json_formatter():
    return logging.Formatter('{"@timestamp": "%(asctime)s", ' +
        '"log.level": "%(levelname)s", ' +
        '"file.name": "%(filename)s", ' +
        '"message": "%(message)s", ' +
        '"error.stack_trace": "%(stack_info)s", ' +
        '"error.message": "%(exc_info)s"}')

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)

stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
stream_handler.setFormatter(get_json_formatter())

log.addHandler(stream_handler)
log.propagate = False

log.info('This works fine')

log.error('Stack is printed twice when stack_info=True', stack_info=True)
```

This code allows the stack trace to be included in the JSON formatted output, but it will also print the Stack Trace one additional time:

```
{"@timestamp": "2020-07-23 14:10:49,718", "log.level": "INFO", "file.name": "example.py", "message": "This works fine", "error.stack_trace": "None", "error.message": "None"}
{"@timestamp": "2020-07-23 14:10:50,817", "log.level": "ERROR", "file.name": "example.py", "message": "Stack is printed twice when stack_info=True", "error.stack_trace": "Stack (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.7.94776\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\__main__.py", line 45, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.7.94776\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.7.94776\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 267, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(options.target, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 265, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Source\example.py", line 23, in <module>
    log.error('Stack is printed twice when stack_info=True', stack_info=True)", "error.message": "None"}
Stack (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.7.94776\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\__main__.py", line 45, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.7.94776\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.7.94776\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 267, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(options.target, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 265, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Source\example.py", line 23, in <module>
    log.error('Stack is printed twice when stack_info=True', stack_info=True)
```

I've tried setting the log.propagate flag to False which has been suggested in other posts, but this does not have any effect.

My question is how you can include the stack_info in the JSON, without the stack trace being printed a second time.

Comment: <disclosure: I'm the maintainer of the below library and an employee of Elastic>

Not a direct solution to your problem but you may find this library useful: https://github.com/elastic/ecs-logging-python

Doesn't handle `stack_info=True` yet but I can add that as a feature :) The library already supports ECS and capturing exceptions with `exc_info=True`.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into that library for sure! :)